# Finding a homeomorphism between naturals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Are $\mathbb N$ with topology $\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}, \{5, 6\}, \{7, 8\}, \ldots$ and all unions of these, and $\mathbb N$ with topology $\{1, 3\}, \{2, 4\}, \{5, 7\}, \{6, 8\}, \{9, 11\}, \{10, 12\}, \ldots$ and all unions of these homeomorphic?

Name the topologies $t, t'$ respectively and let the would-be homeomorphism be $f$. Since we are dealing with $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ we can definitely find a bijection. Now $\{6, 8\}$ is in $t'$ and so it's open. If $f$ were to be continuous $f^{-1}(\{6, 8\})$ would exist and be in $t$. Say, $f^{-1}(\{6, 8\}) = \{7, 8\}$. For that to happen we want, say, $6 \to 7$ and $8 \to 8$.

Bijection is guaranteed, but how do we find one in a way where every element in $t'$ has a unique pre-image in $t$?

Comment: Try thinking about just the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ instead of $\Bbb N$, with two topologies just as in your question except the list stops after the first two sets. Can you show these are homeomorphic?

Comment: Sure, just send $1\mapsto 1,2\mapsto 3, 3\mapsto 2, 4\mapsto 4...$ Basically $f(n)=n$ for $n\equiv 0,1\pmod 4,$ $f(4n-2)=4n-1, $$f(4n-1)=4n-2.$

Comment: Thomas is correct. In particular, mapping in this way (or using any two enumerations of the above bases and mapping the two members of the $n$'th basis set of $t$ to the two members of the $n$'th basis set of $t'$) guarantees a surjection since both members in the $n$'th basis set of $t'$ get mapped to by the members of the $n$'th basis set of $t$, and it is injective since each $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ is found in only one member (set) of either basis. It is not hard to show that such a map is both open and continuous.